# LazyVGrid two columns align each column item to the bottom of the previous item in column

Tags: swiftui

I created a LazyVGrid in swiftui which exists inside a ScrollView. It works but when i have different heights in each column item i want the next column item to align at the bottom side of the previous item separately in each column. Here is the code:

```
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 10), GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 0, alignment: .topLeading)], spacing: 10)
                {
                    ForEach(searchResults, id: \.id) { poem in
                        NavigationLink {} label: {
                                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                    ZStack{
                                        HStack (alignment: .top) {
                                            Text(poem.poemBody)
                                                .lineLimit(10)
                                                .font(.headline)                                                    
                                          .foregroundColor(AppColors.backgroundColor)
                                                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                        }
                                        Spacer()
                                    }
                                }
                                .padding()
                                .background(AppColors.backgroundButtonColor)
                                .overlay(
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                        .stroke(AppColors.backgroundColor, lineWidth: 2)
                                )
                               .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                               .alignmentGuide(.top, computeValue: { _ in 0 })
                        }
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.top, 10)
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Check the image to see the result of the code. I am trying to achieve a feed like pinterest instead of pictures i am adding text for the content.

As you notice the left column has an item that has a different height. So i need to make this item align to the bottom side of the previous item and so on.

The result should be like this but instead of pictures i will use text

[image]

Any ideas on how to do this?